# How to resolve Module Not Found

Tags: python

Hello guys i am trying to create a simple project with flask and it is my first time using **init**.py file. The tree structure is like this

```
FlaskApi/venv
├── lib64 -> lib
├── flaskapi
│   ├── generate_dummy_data.py
│   └── models.py
|   └── routes.py
│   └── __init__.py
    └── linked_list.py
│   └── sqlitedb.db
├── pyvenv.cfg
└── run.py
```

My generate_dummy_data.py file  import is like this:

```
from flaskapi import db
from flaskapi.models import User, BlogPost
```

My **init**.py file is like this:

```
from flask import Flask

from sqlite3 import Connection as SQLite3Connection
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///sqlitedb.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = 0
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

My models.py file is like this:

```
from flaskapi import db
from datetime import datetime
```

When i try to run the file generate_dummy_data.file i get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskapi'
```

Can someone pls explain to me why this is happening? Thank you guys for your time

Comment: I encountered the same issue when using venv in  Pycharm. I just closed the IDE and reopened it, the issue was solved. But I am not sure if this applies to your issue.

Comment: @VaeJiang nope still the same error

Comment: first you could check `os.getcwd()` to see `Current Working Directory`. PyCharm may run code in different folder than `FlaskApi/venv` so `import` may not find `flaskapi`- and this may need to add `FlaskApi/venv` to list `sys.path` before `import`

Comment: you run `from flaskapi import db` in `generate_dummy_data.py` which is already in folder `flaskapi` - but this means it search module `flaskapi` inside folder `flaskapi`, not module `flaskapi` in folder `FlaskApi/venv`. It may need use dot `.` to use relative import like `from . import db` and `from .models import User, BlogPost`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running `generate_dummy_data.py` from the command line, you should move it out of the flaskapi folder (to the same level as the run.py script). I.e:

```
FlaskApi/venv
├── lib64 -> lib
├── flaskapi
|   |
│   └── models.py
|   └── routes.py
│   └── __init__.py
    └── linked_list.py
│   └── sqlitedb.db
├── pyvenv.cfg
└── run.py
|--- generate_dummy_data.py <- should be here
```